# is there any possible for user login and then root login with the same connection using ssh2 php

Tags: php, authentication, libssh2

I am trying to connect server using ssh2 functions with php.

server connection using

```
$server_con = ssh2_connect("server","portno");
```

authenticate the connection like

```
ssh2_auth_password($server_con,"username","pwd");
```

i can use this ssh2 auth password for only once for a connection. 
if i logged as a user i cannot able to switch as a root in same connection.

is there any possible for root login after user login with in the same connection or may i use any other authentication method to connect via ssh2 php ??